# Build website using JSP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, jsp, web

I have to build a website which involve e-commerce stuff like it should allow the users to login and then view the available items. Once the user selects the items and makes payment, it may need additional information in the form of some images/videos to complete the order. So, after payment step, it prompts the user to upload the file and when the file is uploaded on the server, request is complete and the user is kept informed about the status.

All the core functionality is already implemented using REST-ful webservices. I am not able to decide if I should implement the website using HTML+JS (using AJAX to call webservices) or should still use JSP and call webservices using java at server side? Someone suggested me that using JSP is better since it will execute on server side and hence will be secured and faster. But, I somehow feel that HTML+JS is easier to go. Is there some specific advantage to use a server side script like JSP for this purpose? Any ideas are most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Yes server side scripting will be fruitful for this purpose for security constraints. Or you can use angular js though they are easy to learn and they are secure and can make fast XHR request response. :)